# Getting error when an SQL Service Provider is set on the App.config by the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

My class and I were building an application using Visual Studio 2012 and the Entity Framework, and at the time when we wanted to compile the program, it was giving us an error described below:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' 
                                               occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' 
                                          occurred in UPC.Cerberos.DL.DALC.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' 
                                            occurred in UPC.Cerberos.BL.BC.dll
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DefaultInstance()

   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection..ctor(String 
                                                       nameOrConnectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)

   at UPC.Cerberos.DL.DataModel.CerberosEntities..ctor() in 
                                  e:\NET_19-05-2014\Solucion WF EF\Solucion WF 
                      EF\UPC.Cerberos.DL.DataModel\Cerberos.Context.cs:line 18

   at UPC.Cerberos.DL.DALC.UsuarioDALC.UsuarioAutenticar(String sUsuario, 
                      String sContrasena) in e:\NET_19-05-2014\Solucion WF EF
                      \Solucion WF EF\UPC.Cerberos.DL.DALC
                       \UsuarioDALC.cs:line 28
   at UPC.Cerberos.BL.BC.UsuarioBC.UsuarioAutenticar(String sUsuario, 
                      String sContrasena) in e:\NET_19-05-2014\Solucion WF EF\
                      Solucion WF EF\UPC.Cerberos.BL.BC\UsuarioBC.cs:line 25
   at UPC.DotNetStore.PL.UI.WindowsForms.frmLogin.btnIngresar_Click(Object 
                      sender, EventArgs e) in e:\NET_19-05-2014\Solucion WF EF\
                      Solucion WF
                      EF\UPC.DotNetStore.PL.UI.WindowsForms\frmLogin.cs:line 31
```

We searched about this, tried a few things, but nothing worked, until we paid attention to a warning:

```
Warning 1   The element 'entityFramework' has invalid child element 
   'providers'. List of possible elements expected: 'contexts'. E:\NET_19-05-
      2014\Solucion WF EF\Solucion WF EF\UPC.DotNetStore.BL.BC\App.config   13
                                                6   UPC.DotNetStore.BL.BC
```

The providers lines were automatically added by the Entity Framework, so it is curious how removing those lines solved the problem (see lines info below).

My question is, why was that error happening? What are those providers for? Did we make a mistake removing them?

I'm adding the code I had in the App.config file and the App.config files from both DataModels I created for the solution.

**Windows Form project App.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DotNetStoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DotNetStore.csdl|res://*/DotNetStore.ssdl|res://*/DotNetStore.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=DotNetStore;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=passw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="CerberosEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Cerberos.csdl|res://*/Cerberos.ssdl|res://*/Cerberos.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=Cerberos;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=passw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
      <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Providers lines I removed:**

```
  <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
```

**Data Model Database 1 App.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DotNetStoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DotNetStore.csdl|res://*/DotNetStore.ssdl|res://*/DotNetStore.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=DotNetStore;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=passw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**Data Model Database 2 App.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CerberosEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Cerberos.csdl|res://*/Cerberos.ssdl|res://*/Cerberos.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=Cerberos;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=passw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**Version information:**

Visual Studio 2012 Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4

Entity Framework 5.0.0

.NET Framework Version 4.5.50938